# Magento2 Require js not a function

Tags: magento2, requirejs

When running grunt exec require.js not a function error appeared.
[image]

Comment: delete the existing require js from  pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Namespace/Theme/en_US requirejs-config.js path and refresh the page again so it will regenerate it and solve the error of js not found.

Comment: If you fix this issue please let me know.  I have faced this issue in Magento_Backend/js/bootstrap/editor.js

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps . I think it's solve your problem

1. Remove Your Cache
2. Clean theme by command : grunt clean
3. Run CMD command prompt with administrator privilege
4. run command : grunt exec:yourthemename
5. run command : grunt less:yourthemename
6. run command : grunt watch

Basically working and the right solution, but with the limitations of [#6367](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6367)